# I am able to run this program no problem, but receive a PermissionError when trying to run it on another computer

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library

I inserted an image to a Tkinter window using the following code

```
    self.path = 'C:/Users/Paro1052/Pictures/coresolutionlogo.jpg'
    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.path))


    self.label = Label(root, image = self.img)
    self.label.pack()
    self.Main = Frame(self.master)
```

I am able to run the code and have the image display on the Tkinter window, but when I try to run the program on another computer, I get a Permission Error ([Errno13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Paro1052/Pictures/coresolutionlogo.jpg').

Is there a way to change the path to allow everyone to access the .jpg file and run the program?

Comment: Does the other computer also have a folder named `C:/Users/Paro1052/Pictures`, and do you have read access to that folder?

Comment: No, it's unique to my account. I'm not sure where to save it where it would be accessible to both of us.